# Find commands don't work in script only

Tags: bash, find

I have a script that searches specific locations for .txt files and outputs the results to stdout, and to a file using the tee command. At least it's supposed to. I'm having some strange issues with it however. Here's the code:

```
echo -e "${HIGHLIGHT}Sensitive files:${OFF}"
echo "## Sensitive files:" >> $ofile
for file in $(cat $1); do ls -lh $file 2>/dev/null; done | tee -a $ofile
echo " " | tee -a $ofile
echo -e "${HIGHLIGHT}Suids:${OFF}"
echo "## Suids:" >> $ofile
find / -type f \( -perm -04000 -o -perm -02000 \) -exec ls -Alh {} \; 2>/dev/null | tee -a $ofile
echo " " | tee -a $ofile
echo -e "${HIGHLIGHT}Owned by root only:${OFF}"
echo "## Owned by root only:" >> $ofile
find / -type f -user root \( -perm -04000 -o -perm -02000 \) -exec ls -lg {} \; 2>/dev/null | tee -a $ofile
echo " " | tee -a $ofile

# Text files
echo -e "${HIGHLIGHT}Text files:${OFF}"
echo "## Text files:" >> $ofile
find /etc -type f -name *.txt -exec ls -lh {} \; 2>/dev/null | tee -a $ofile
find /home -type f -name *.txt -exec ls -lh {} \; 2>/dev/null | tee -a $ofile
find /root -type f -name *.txt -exec ls -lh {} \; 2>/dev/null | tee -a $ofile
```

The strange thing is that all of the commands work just fine, except for the find searches for .txt files at the bottom. None of those commands work in the script, yet if I copy and paste them into the terminal and run it **exactly as they were in the script**, they work just fine. How is this even possible?

Comment: I highly recommend the shellcheck tool (which can be installed offline or used via the web at http://www.shellcheck.net/). It can help you point out issues in your shell scripts you might not be aware of. It warns of your find searches "Quote the parameter to -name so the shell won't interpret it." And this is I think where your problem is here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote or escape the `*` in your `-name` patterns, otherwise the shell tries to expand it and use the expanded form in its place in the command line.

```
find /etc -type f -name '*.txt' -exec ls -lh {} \; 2>/dev/null | tee -a $ofile
```

and the others being similar will work